# How to carry out constrained regression in R

Tags: r, regression

Say I have a simple regression equation

`lm(y~., newdata=df)`

I know that if I want to reduce the intercept to 0, I write

`lm(y+0., newdata=df)`

However, is there a way to produce a step regression, all while constraining each coefficient to a specific range? For instance:

`step(lm(y~.>1000, newdata=df)`

The above does not work, but is there a way to say produce a regression that basically produces the best fit and forces each coefficient to be greater than 1,000? Or, less than a specified range.

```
#as per Gautam    
minfunc <- function(coefs){
      out <- sum(sapply(3:314, function(z) return(coefs[z]*test2[, z])))
      return(out)
    }


    par = c(1, 1, 30) # initial value
    lb = c(-1, -1, -300000) # lower bound for coefs
    ub = c(30, 30, 30000) # upper bound 

    result <- hjkb(par = par, fn = minfunc, lower = lb, upper = ub)
```

Thank you,

Comment: You could run a constrained optimization in R. Basically the coefficients are unknown but are bounded. To solve you may choose to minimize the squared error (or RMSE). You'd want to select a gradient free algorithm ideally. Check out the `dfoptim` library.

Comment: @Gautam thank you for your response. I have actually been looking into this and playing around with the code. But unable to figure out how to properly code it. Mind you I have only been  using R for the past 2-3 weeks. Hence, newbie. Is there a way to code it in such a way to include all variables without manually typing all 300 independent variables I have similar to the lm() above using "."?

Comment: Yes, I'll post an example in the answer - too long to post here.

Comment: your argument in `sapply` is not correct - it needs to be a vector. just `sapply(3:314, function(z) ... )` should work.

Comment: `Error in `[.data.table`(test2, , z) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'z' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..z]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.`

Getting the following error

Comment: my bad, you don't need it to be a `data.table`. `data.frame` is fine. you can remove the library too. I was going to use another method before but then changed my mind.

Comment: Hi Gautam, I am still getting an error  Error in coefs[z] * test2[, z] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Not sure why taht is - I didn't get that kind of error. On a secondary note, depending on your problem structure, might be worthwhile to look into `Rcplex`.

Comment: Check out related post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21565/how-do-i-fit-a-constrained-regression-in-r-so-that-coefficients-total-1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a code that ought to work. You'll need to tweak the bounds etc. to get what you want.

```
library(data.table)
library(dfoptim)

minfunc <- function(coefs){
  # using mtcars as the sample data - you would read in your data here
  df <- as.data.table(mtcars)

  out <- (sum(coefs[1]*df$cyl + coefs[2]*df$wt + coefs[3]) - sum(df$mpg))^2
  return(out)
}


par = c(1, 1, 30) # initial value
lb = c(-1, -1, -300000) # lower bound for coefs
ub = c(30, 30, 30000) # upper bound 

result <- hjkb(par = par, fn = minfunc, lower = lb, upper = ub)
```

comparing to `lm`:

```
> lm(mpg ~ cyl + wt, data = mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + wt, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl           wt  
     39.686       -1.508       -3.191  

> result$par
[1]  0.00000 -1.00000 23.30788 
#        cyl       wt constant
```

The results are different, as expected. The convergence and final result depend on the choice of optimization algorithm and the initial input. I've used `hjkb` as an example but it is not the best algorithm. You may want to try a different algorithm based on your needs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your sample answer. The issue to implement would require me to type out all 300 coefficients. Is there a way to say the code should select all coefficients and apply the algo to all?

Comment: you can use `rep` to specify the initial value and bounds for `coefs` (e.g. `rep(4, ncols(df))`) . For the multiplication, convert the data to matrix and use `crossprod` or use `sapply` etc (e.g. `sum(sapply(1:ncol(df), function(z) return(coefs[z]*df[, z])))`). to get what you want.

Comment: I am still having issues, I updated OP to show what I did thus far using your assistance.