Forcing a multiple regression model's coefficient to be positive
I was wondering if there is a way to force a multiple regression model's coefficient to be a positive number. For example, in the code below I would like to constrain x2 to be a positive number. Thank you!
tc <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV")
model <- train(form = y ~ x1 + x2, data = df, method = "lm",
               metric = "MAE", maximize = T,
               trControl = tc, na.action = na.omit)


Possible of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766431/how-to-carry-out-constrained-regression-in-r, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244898/force-certain-parameters-to-have-positive-coefficients-in-lm. If you would like to use them in caret I think you will need to create your own model: https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html
